# Ошибка или баг при подключении службы (wsdl)

Tags: c#, .net-core, service, веб-служба, wsdl

При подключении этой же службы в .net всё работает. А в .net core 3.1 выдает эту ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем может быть причина.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `в .net` какой версии?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Microsoft сочла WCF устаревшей технологией, поэтому не реализовала её в .NET Core. Ищите сторонние реализации (есть такие).